# Is watching kdrama haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I've been watching kdrama and I came across a video saying anime and kdrama are haram and I never knew Abt this so please tell me and give me proof like a Hadith or in the Quran saying that<3

Comment: What is kdrama?

Comment: Kdrama is a Korean drama. It is a Korean movie or a show where there's only Korean people in it and they only speak Korean.

Answer (score 1):

It is haraam because of following:

1. Wasting time
2. Looking at forbidden things
3. Listening to music
4. Imitation of the kuffaar

Proof for point 1:

> Ibn Abbas reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him,
> said, “There are two blessings which many people waste: health and
> free time.” Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 6049

Proof for point 2:

> “Tell the believing men to lower their gaze (from looking at forbidden
> things), and protect their private parts (from illegal sexual acts).
> That is purer for them. Verily, Allâh is All-Aware of what they do.
> And tell the believing women to lower their gaze (from looking at
> forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal
> sexual acts)” [al-Noor 24:30-31].

Proof for point 3:

> “And of mankind is he who purchases idle talks (i.e. music, singing)
> to mislead (men) from the path of Allah…” [Luqman 31:6]

Proof for point 4:

> It was narrated that ‘Abd-Allaah ibn ‘Umar said: The Prophet (peace
> and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever imitates a people
> is one of them.” Narrated by Abu Dawood, 3512; classed as saheeh by
> al-Albaani in Irwa’ al-Ghaleel, 2691.

Comment: Thank you for giving proof and for telling me I have stopped watching it and focused on my Deen jazakallah Khair!

Comment: Does singing come under idle talk? How? it's literally permissible and there is I'jma on this if it doesn't include music or inappropriate words in it.